# Php write some variables in the same line

Tags: php, fwrite

I would like to ask a simple question.
I have different variables $a='a', $b='b', $c='c' in PHP. I would like to save the target txt file with the format like

```
"a b c".
```

But if I use fwrite, I could only write the variables in a column.

```
"a
 b
 c"
```

Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance.

PS

I found problem may be here. Each variable I used is from the lines of a existed file.

```
 $lines= files('abc.txt'); 
 $a = $lines[0]; //like this
```

In this circumstance, the variables contains also a line feed ? Am I write ?

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 2):

Use a single fwrite statement to write them all at once:

```
fwrite( $fp, "$a $b $c" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Join them as a single string:

```
$str = $a.' '.$b.' '.$c;
```

Then write them to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about your query but as per what I have understood is that you want something like this:

```
$a='a';
$b='b';
$c='c';
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp,$a." ");
fwrite($fp,$b." ");
fwrite($fp,$c);
fclose($fp);
```